# How to remove check out status from source safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I had two copies of checked out project in two diffent locations, but one got deleted. now in source safe its showing that the project is checked out in the deleted location. But the project is not in that location. Is there any way to remove the "Checked out" location information from source safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perform Undo Check Out and then check out the files to your new location